# Analyze rarely populated fields in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have a mongodb collection with close to 100,000 records and each record has around 5000 keys. Lot of this is empty. How can I find (maybe visually represent) this emptiness of data. 
In other words, I would like to analyze the type of values in each key. What would be the right approach for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look to MongoDB aggregation strategies. Check out [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

From how you exposed your problem, I could totally see an accumulator over the number of keys of each record.
As an example, with the appropriate thresholds and transformation, such an operation could basically return you the records grouped by number of keys (or an array solely populated with the number of keys for each record).

Such an approach could also allow you to perform some data analysis over the keys used for each record.